# Redux form or simple form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

Often in the interview questions it is heard that Why one should use redux form in the ReactJs instead of simple form. which extra ordinary facilities it provides to the developer ? Then what should be proper answer for this.

Comment: It all boils down to the performance and best practices the library uses. Redux-form is designed with this goal. If you don't want to reinvent the wheel just adopt.

Answer (score 4):

Now that is known why to keep the form data in the state and you reason if that makes sense for your application we can come back to our main subject. Given that the application uses React and Redux there are two main options:

- implements for each field an event handler that dispatches an action creator, and the reducer that will receive the action… All the redux stuff.
- ✔️ Or we could use a library that does all this work for us.

Redux-Form is a great option to do that job to you. It **keeps track of all common application form state** such as:

- The fields that are in the form;
- The values of each field;
- The focused field;
- If the field values are valid;
- The fields that the user have interacted with;
- If the form is being submitted;
- If is happening any asynchronous validation.

Back then Redux-Form didn't have an established alternative, but nowadays we have great options such as [Formik](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik) and [Final-Form](https://github.com/final-form/final-form), and both use React's component state.

When writing a Redux application, we *should* keep all the data that matters to the application in the in the application state as long as it makes sense. But the point is, reason about what make more sense for your application and pick your choice.

Inspired by: [Guilherme Gonçalves](https://medium.com/dailyjs/why-build-your-forms-with-redux-form-bcacbedc9e8)

Answer (score 2):

It makes life easier when it comes to integrating forms into our React applications as opposed to putting it all together manually with Redux.

All of our data is held inside the Redux store and anytime a user changes an element, we call an action creator that attempts to change that data inside Redux.

Redux Form attempts to automate some of that process.

So we might have some input element that is going to be assigned a value and `onChange` handler by our application because we never let the DOM hold information about our app.

We are going to have some reducer that holds all the state of different forms inside our application.

All of our form data will exist inside of our Redux store and all that data is maintained by a reducer.

To ensure we can get the data from the store to input elements we are going to have `mapStateToProps` that takes the form data and passes it to our components via props. Then we ensure we take the props object and pass them into our different input elements as values.

Anytime a user makes a change to an element we have a callback handler that calls an action creator and try to update the form data inside of the Redux store.

Redux Form is essentially going to do everything I wrote above for us, because the process I just described above is so repetitive, Redux Form will automate this for us.

Redux Form allows us to abstract that work out to it. Redux Form will have a reducer that we wire up to our application. Its included with the Redux Form library.

We are not going to write any `mapStateToProps` function. We will not have to write action creators. All we have to do is ensure we get some form information into the input element and ensure that the input element understands it needs to call a callback handler provided by Redux form anytime it gets changed. All this goes on behind the scenes, automatically by Redux Form.